# How to work with Qml Fonttype in javascript?

Tags: javascript, text, fonts, qml

I have the following issue, that pops up when using Qml and working with fonts.

I use the following code, to dynamically choose between differently sized fonts:

```
function getValueFontDefault(valueAreaHeight, valueAreaWidth) {
    var fonts = [font0,
                 font1,
                 font2,
                 font3]

    for( var fontCandidate in fonts){
        if ( fontCandidate.pixelSize <= valueAreaHeight ){
            checkTextDummy.font = fontCandidate;

            if( checkTextDummy.paintedWidth <= valueAreaWidth ){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return fontCandidate;
}

Text{
    id: checkTextDummy
    visible: false
    text: "this is the longest example text thinkable" 
}
```

The fonts are of "font" type in Qml. My problem is, that javascript cannot put them in a "var". It always says, that fontCandidate.pixelSize was undefined. Using not a loop over the different fonts, but using them explicitly (i.e. font0.pixelSize), it works.

So how do I treat the Qml fonts in javascript? What is the correct way to put them in variables and work with them?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Greetings from Germany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. It didn't have anything to do with Qml and javascript, but with my lack of knowledge with js.

In fact the for loops are no for_each as I assumed. They are simple for loops. So putting it correctly it becomes:

```
    for( var idx in fonts){
        var fontCandidate = fonts[idx]
        checkTextDummy.font = fontCandidate
```

And then it works as intended. Thank you anyway for your help.